# KnockoutJS: How should I deal with heavy widget initialization code?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, knockout.js, widget, jquery-select2

I'm currently trying to optimize our application that uses KnockoutJS for view binding and rendering. We discovered a huge bottleneck with a growing dataset size in the following scenario:

- The dataset (observableArray) is displayed in an html table.
- 50 rows are displayed at the same time.
- Each field in the row-model is an observable as the data is inline editable (input, select, ...)
- Per row exist 8 selects that are initialized with the Select2 Widget (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2) and a jQuery datepicker.

I already implemented these KnockoutJS performance tips, which I found on different sites:

- The observable array is published with the full dataset (call of the observable) and not with multiple push() calls.
- I'm using the template-binding in conjunction with the foreach option, as advised on multiple sites, and not both split up as separate binds.
- Datepicker and Select2 are implemented as custom knockout bindingHandlers.
- ko.applyBindings is invoked directly with the table-element as second parameter, so that not the whole DOM is bound by knockout.

But the main bottleneck in my opinion seems to be the initialization of the additional widgets. I measured the creation of a Select2 widget, which takes ~15ms. Of course that  cummulates quickly with 50 rows and 8 columns. So, a single call on the observable array to load the full dataset takes up to 10 seconds! During this time, the Browser is under heavy load and becomes unresponsive, which is a no-go usability wise.

This leads up to my questions:

- Has someone experienced a similar scenario and how was it handled?
- Is there a better way to initialize third-party widgets with knockout?
- Are there alternative ways (using KnockoutJS) to solve this problem?

Comment: Are your plugins (select2 and datepicker) required at all times? Or can you enter an "edit mode" and init them only then?

Answer (score 0):

### Has someone experienced a similar scenario and how was it handled?

I have an interactive table on my page, which I display using the **[HandsOnTable plugin](http://handsontable.com/)**. The table has about *15 columns* and I need to display up to *250 rows*.

I bind it to an `observableArray`, and, at first, the `observableArray` contained only observables.

I was not satisfied with the speed of it in old versions of IE I am required to maintain (IE8/9, worked ok with IE11/recent Chrome), and **made the decision to remove all observables inside the `observableArray`**.

It is not really in the spirit of knockout and I am not so proud of this solution, but it does work much faster.

Handsontable lets you handle some events, in which I update the `observableArray` just like a regular array and then run the `valueHasMutated` function to notify the changes of the array.

Likewise, my custom binding handler watches changes on the whole `observableArray` and updates the table as needed.

I think the other difference with your solution is that Handsontable turns into edit mode only when needed, thus the plugins (like datepicker) load only then.

### Is there a better way to initialize third-party widgets with knockout?

Maybe you can enter edit mode only when the line/cell is selected. You could then use an `if` binding to init and display your widgets only then.